# Redux Saga yields very slowly when polling multiple endpoints

Tags: redux-saga

I'm polling two APIs at the same time using redux-saga and I wish to control both of the pollings with `race` with an action that can stop both of them:

```
function* root() {
    yield all([
      call(startSimulation),
      takeEvery(RESTART_SIMULATION, stopAndStartSimulation),
      takeEvery(STOP_SIMULATION, haltSimulation),
  ])


export function* startPolling(vin: string) {
  yield all([call(pollEventsSagaWorker), call(pollStatusSagaWorker, vin)])
}

export function* initiateSimulation() {
  const vin = yield select(vinSelector)
  yield call(startPolling, vin)
}

export function* haltSimulation() {
  const runningSimulation = yield select(simulationsDataSelector)
  if (runningSimulation) {
    yield put(deleteSimulation(runningSimulation.id))
  }
}

export function* startSimulation() {
  while (true) {
    yield take(INIT_SIMULATION)
    yield race([call(initiateSimulation), take(STOP_SIMULATION)])
  }
}

export function* stopAndStartSimulation() {
  yield put(stopSimulation())
  // do some other stuff
}
```

`stopSimulation()` is action creator (with `STOP_SIMULATION` type).

Here is an example to the polling saga:

```
export function* pollEventsSagaWorker() {
  while (true) {
    try {
      yield put(fetchEvents())
      yield delay(EVENT_POLL_INTERVAL)
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('polling failed', err)
    }
  }
}
```

Problem is when I call `STOP_SIMULATION` it takes several seconds until things move on (while the UI is stuck also) - what could be the cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some pattern in redux-saga docs that you can use in order to solve this case by using the `cancel` instead of `race`. Using it will:

> cancel the current Effect where the task is blocked at the moment of
>   cancellation.

I have added an example (as identical as I could to your code) that triggers the cancel effect right after `STOP_SIMULATION` action is fired.

```
// THE CONTROL LOOP
export function* mainSaga() {
    while (yield take(INIT_SIMULATION)) {
        // starts the task in the background
        const task = yield fork(pollEventsSagaWorker);

        // wait for the user stop action
        yield take(STOP_SIMULATION);
        // user clicked stop.
        // cancel the polling by causing the forked saga to enter its finally block
        yield cancel(task);
    }
}
```

That will cause `pollEventsSagaWorker` to propagate the cancellation downward to any sub tasks.

> If the callee is still pending and the caller decides to cancel
>   the operation, it triggers a kind of a signal that propagates down to
>   the callee (and possibly to any deep operations called by the callee
>   itself). All deeply pending operations will be cancelled.

```
export function* pollEventsSagaWorker() {
    try {
        while (true) {
            yield put(fetchEvents());
            yield delay(EVENT_POLL_INTERVAL);
        }
    } finally {
        if (yield cancelled()) {
            console.error('polling stopped');
        }
    }
}
```

Check this referenece [task-cancellation](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/TaskCancellation.html)

Comment: Thank you, this solution is prettier, solves my problem (that, apparently happened only with devtools open)